# Triggers hidden

Tags: mysql, trigger

I had to edit a trigger in my MySQL database.
But when typing `SHOW TRIGGERS` nothing appear.

My database is the only one selected but I also tried `SHOW TRIGGERS FROM myDBname`. Still nothing.

This trigger fill a certain field based on other fields. And When I insert something in this table, the trigger works.

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| job_id | job_machine |      job_start      | job_end | job_name |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
|      1 |           1 | 2015-11-23 16:03:00 |         |          |
|      1 |           1 | 2015-11-23 16:03:00 |         | 15112311 |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
```

And when I insert a new row with a `job_machine` and a `job_start` the field `job_name` is auto-completed

Comment: could You provide little more information? what version of mysql? how exactly You run command? (better copy past from console). I test it on 2 different version - all work. and one more - who definer of trigger and from which user You run command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the TRIGGER privilege as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger

So if your database was called `foo` and your user was `'bar'@'localhost'` you would need to run:

```
GRANT TRIGGER ON foo.* to 'bar'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 1):

main reason for this - triggers created by one user (for example root) and select run from other, which not have full rights - You must have **Trigger** privilege for display triggers from database.

in other case - result will be empty.